# How to split break lines with Bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, ifs

If you have a string with a delimiter, let's say a `,` character, you could use `IFS` just like that:

```
text=some,comma,separated,text
IFS="," read -ra ADDR <<< "$text"

for i in ${ADDR[@]}
do
    echo $i
done
```

Each word will be printed in a new line. But if you grab the result of command like `ls` and then try to split it on the `\n` you don't get to the same result:

```
results=$(ls -la)
IFS="\n" read -ra ADDR <<< "$results"

for i in ${ADDR[@]}
do
    echo $i
done
```

It only prints 2 lines, and they are not even the file entries. It is

```
total
36
```

The first line of the `ls` command output.

Can someone give a little help?
If it is not the correct way, how is that?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hopefully this was just an academic example but make sure to read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) before doing any more parsing `ls` output or writing shell loops to manipulate text.

Comment: `IFS="\n"` adds the two characters ``\`` and `n` to `IFS`, not a single newline character. You would want `IFS=$'\n'`, but this is not a good way to iterate over the files in a directory as Ed Morton points out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read` usually reads until it reaches newline, unless you tell it otherwise using `-d`.

In this example, we use `-d $'\0'`. This has the shell read until it reaches a null character (which it won't in the output of `ls`). Then `IFS=$'\n'` causes the shell to split on newline and assign each line as an array element. Note the use of `$'...'` instead of `"..."` to interpret the escape sequences.

```
results=$(ls -la)

IFS=$'\n' read -ra ADDR -d $'\0' <<< "$results"

for i in "${ADDR[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Last but not least, we have to quote both the substitutions of the array and `$i`.

Comment: Wouldn't `ls -la | while read line; do echo "$line"; done` do it, too?

Comment: @U.Windl  possibly, but the OP was asking what was wrong with his code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `readarray` or `mapfile` to read many lines into an array. Much simpler. Make sure to quote the variable expansions in the loop as well.

```
results=$(ls -la)
readarray -t ADDR <<< "$results"

for i in "${ADDR[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Or skip the `$results` variable:

```
readarray -t ADDR < <(ls -la)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of output you are looking for, but guessed that you are looking for each line broken into tokens. Here is one way:

```
/bin/ls -la | while read -ra line
do
    # Whole line
    echo "Line: >${line[@]}<"

    # Break each line into tokens
    for i in ${line[@]}
    do
        echo "- $i"
    done
done
```

## Notes

- The first line takes the output of `ls -la` and feeds into the while loop, reading each line as an array
- Inside the while loop, we can deal with line as a whole, or as individual tokens

## Output Excerpt

```
Line: >-rw-r--r-- 1 haiv staff 142 May 8 10:56 star.md<
- -rw-r--r--
- 1
- haiv
- staff
- 142
- May
- 8
- 10:56
- star.md
Line: >drwxr-xr-x 7 haiv staff 224 May 2 10:26 tailstring<
- drwxr-xr-x
- 7
- haiv
- staff
- 224
- May
- 2
- 10:26
- tailstring
```